# How to install NetBeans with java ee edition?

Tags: netbeans

I am using ubuntu 16.04.I want to install NetBeans with java ee edition.So please guide me to install it.I am new to ubuntu so please help me.

Answer (score 0):

To download the package, you can go to the link :

> https://netbeans.org/downloads/start.html?platform=linux&lang=en&option=javaee

After downloading it, open the folder; open a shell by right clicking and SELECTING `oPEN IN TERMINAL`

Then run the command :

```
sudo ./<name of the downloaded file>
```

You will be prompted for password; the installation should start from there.